# A question about relative clause and present participle

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis, present-participles

Consider:

1. > He hurt his arm while he was playing tennis.
2. > He hurt his arm playing tennis.
3. > He hurt his arm **while playing** tennis.

I can justify sentences 1 and 2 (2 is reduced version of 1). But, I have no idea about grammarian structure of the  **while playing** in sentence three (3).

---

**Edit**:

I want to now is there any specific rule for the reduction that happened in the sentence 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your third sentence '*while*' is a conjunction that means "at the same time as".  Also, the implied "*he was*" is omitted right before the '*playing*', so the full version would be

> He hurt his arm while he was playing tennis.

which is exactly as your sentence 1.

The difference in meaning between those and the sentence 2 is that the injury "he" received is directly related to playing tennis in (2), and only temporal connection between the playing and the injury exists in sentences (1) and (3).  Of course, it is likely that "during" is understood as "because of", especially about an injury; it's not the same if instead of "*hurt himself*" we had "*received a phone call*", for instance.

Comment: the **he is**  has been omitted under what rule ? The reason I ask the question. I know how to reduce the subordinate clauses, but I think this is a different reduction.

Comment: I think it's called "a *reduced (temporal) clause*", see http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-12.html for example.